# Subclass of QAbstractListModel only available as superclass in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a subclass of `QAbstractListModel` called `ObjectListModel` which contains a method `remove()`:

```
class ObjectListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void remove(int index);
}
```

However, when I try to call `remove()` from within QML, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Property 'remove' of object QAbstractListModel(0x13c3c0) is not a function
```

I expose an instance of `ObjectListModel` through a property of `MyApplication`:

```
Q_PROPERTY(ObjectListModel *uploadModel
           MEMBER _uploadModel
           NOTIFY uploadModelChanged)
```

and I register the type as follows in `main()`:

```
qRegisterMetaType<ObjectListModel*>("ObjectListModel*");
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Also, you are registering incorrectly, you need something like:

```
qmlRegisterType<List>("ModuleName", 1, 0, "ObjectListModel");
```

`QObject`s are implicitly meta types, since they get the moc treatment (if you don't forget the macro). So there is no need to registering them as meta types.

Comment: Thanks, it was the missing macro. For some reason I thought because I inherit from `QAbstractListModel` I wouldn't need it again. Also, adding it gave a lot of compiler warnings, running qmake again fixed that though. Actually adding the `Q_OBJECT` macro made it unnecessary to register the class (I'm not planing on instantiating it in QML.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The `Q_OBJECT` macro is missing.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I thought because I'm already inheriting from `QAbstractListModel` this wouldn't be necessary. The compiler was not helpful when it complained after adding `Q_OBJECT`. (Running qmake helped.)

Comment: The `Q_OBJECT` macro is necessary to add type metadata to any `QObject`-deriving class. When you inherit from `QAbstractListModel` and not use the macro, your derived class looks exactly like the most derived class that had the macro - and that's `QAbstractListModel` in your case, exactly as you observed. It was linker that complained since there was no implementation of the methods that `Q_OBJECT` macro adds to the class. Re-running `qmake` added a code generation step to the build so that the implementations would be available to the linker.